# Rspec - wrong number of arguments when raising error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rspec

So in my code I have this method I'm trying to test:

```
  # checks if a file already exists on S3
  def file_exists?(storage_key)
    begin
      s3_resource.bucket(@bucket).object(storage_key).exists?
    rescue Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden => e
      false
    end
  end
```

Now I am trying to make two test cases - one for when the file exists, and one for when it doesn't.

Focusing on the failure case. I want to stub out the `exists?` to raise the `Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden` error so that the `file_exists?` method will return false.

Here's what my test code looks like:

```
  it "returns false if the file doesn't already exist" do
    allow_any_instance_of(Aws::S3::Object).to receive(:exists?).and_raise(
      Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden
    )
    expect(instance.file_exists?('foo')).to be false
  end
```

Running this test I see this:

```
   wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)
   # ./lib/s3_client_builder.rb:48:in `file_exists?'
```

Really not clear what's going on here, since the `file_exists?` method definitely doesn't have an arity of 2 nor does the `exists?` method I'm stubbing.

To diagnose this, I put a breakpoint in the `begin` block. I try and run the `<object>.exists?` line and get the same error.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with:

```
and_raise(
  Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden
)
```

Running this shows the same error:

```
raise(Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden)
```

What does work is this:

```
raise(Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden.new(nil, nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

according to
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Errors/ServiceError.html#initialize-instance_method

the three arguments are

- context (Seahorse::Client::RequestContext)
- message (String)
- data (Aws::Structure) (defaults to: Aws::EmptyStructure.new)

The `message` is where you can add your own information.