# Rspec: How to test an exception is raised in private method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

Getting error while testing an exception in a private method. How to test an exception is raised in private method which is called from a public method?

Public

```
def public_method
    private_method
end
```

Private

```
  def private_method
    tries = 0
    begin
      raise Product::StaleObjectError.new("Product is changed while you were editing") if stale_object?
      // Do some work
      raise Exception.new("Total amount used is greater than approved") if total_approved < 0

      // Save Product
    rescue Product::StaleObjectError => e
      if tries < MAX_RETRIES
        tries += 1
        sleep(1 + tries)
        reload
        retry
      else
        raise Product::StaleObjectError("Product is changed while you were editing")
      end
    end
    attributes
  end
```

Test Case:

```
  before(:each) do
    @prod_v1 = Product.new
  end
  it 'if product stale, then an exception should raise' do
    Product.any_instance.stub(:stale_object?).and_return(true)
    expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:private_method).and_raise(Product::StaleObjectError.new("Product is changed while you were editing"), nil)
    @prod_v1.public_method
  end
```

I am getting following error for test case

```
 Failure/Error: @product_v1.private_method
 Product::StaleObjectError:
   Product is changed while you were editing
 # ./app/models/product.rb:10:in `private_method'
 # ./spec/models/product_spec.rb:67:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried the change the structure of the test case, but still get errors.

```
  it 'if product stale, then an exception should raise' do
   Product.any_instance.stub(:stale_object?).and_return(true)
    expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:private_method).and_raise(Product::StaleObjectError.new(nil, nil))
    @prod_v1.public_method
  end
```

Error

```
    Failure/Error: expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:private_method).and_raise(Product::StaleObjectError.new(nil, nil))
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `and_raise(Product::StaleObjectError.new(nil, nil))`

see this question i asked a while about the same issue:

[Rspec - wrong number of arguments when raising error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40775978/rspec-wrong-number-of-arguments-when-raising-error)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried as you said, However, it is Not working  Error am getting: `    Failure/Error: expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:private_method).and_raise(Product::StaleObjectError.new(nil, nil))
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)`

Comment: Woking, I was not handling the `Product::StaleObjectError` raised by `private_method`. I handled it in `public_method`. Used `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError.new(self, "Test")` instead of  `Product::StaleObjectError`. Thanks @max